# Linear interpolation gives error at specific input values between 70% and 80%

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a very specific excel problem. I have a model where a certain *boost* leads to a certain *rate*. These boosts are defined as 10%, 20%, 30% until 100%. To be able to determine what the rate will be at, for instance, 75%, I want to use linear interpolation.

```
Boost  Rate 
0%      1.50%
10%     1.75%
20%     2,00%
30%     2.25%
40%     2.50%
50%     2.75%
60%     3.00%
70%     3.25%
80%     3.50%
90%     3.75%
100%    4.00%
```

**For the sake of simplicity, these rates are linear distributed, but in reality they are not. I only want to interpolate between the 10% intervals.**

I use a combination of VLOOKUP and the ROUNDUP/ROUNDDOWN functions to make a linear interpolation. For instance: When the boost is 56%, I first rounddown 56% to 50% and use VLOOKUP to retrieve the rate from the table, which returns 2,75%. Then I ROUNDUP 56% to 60% and also retrieve the corresponding rate for that boost, which is 3,00%. Then I take the 3%, substract 2,75% and multiply the outcome by (56% - 50%) / 10%. This results in 0.15%. When I add this to the 2.74% retrieved early, I have the result: 2.90%.

In Excel formulas, it looks like this:

```
=((D5-ROUNDDOWN(D5;1))/0,1)*(VLOOKUP(ROUNDUP(D5;1);$A$2:$B$12;2;0)-VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(D5;1);$A$2:$B$12;2;0))+VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(D5;1);$A$2:$B$12;2;0)
```

Where D5 = the boost percentage you want to get the rate for.

So far so good. This works, *except* for boosts between 70% and 80% **and i just don't understand why.**

This is the output I get:

```
Boost   Rate
53%     2.83%
54%     2.85%
55%     2.88%
56%     2.90%
57%     2.93%
58%     2.95%
59%     2.98%
60%     3.00%
61%     3.03%
62%     3.05%
63%     3.08%
64%     3.10%
65%     3.13%
66%     3.15%
67%     3.18%
68%     3.20%
69%     3.23%
70%     3.25%
71%     #N/A
72%     #N/A
73%     #N/A
74%     #N/A
75%     #N/A
76%     #N/A
77%     #N/A
78%     #N/A
79%     #N/A
80%     3.50%
81%     3.53%
82%     3.55%
83%     3.58%
84%     3.60%
```

I have combed through the internet trying to find a solution, but it's not there. Does anyone know how to this is happening or does anything have an alternative solution?

Comment: Check the formatting of the cells that contain 70%, and also of the table you are doing vlookup against. Probably something is formatted as text instead of percentage.

Comment: @Luuklag Thanks for the suggestion. I checked that and it's not the case. They are all listed as numbers. I started from scratch and again it didn't work. Try reproducing it in Excel and you'll see it won't work.

Comment: Interesting...I also had the same issue you have mentioned with Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1):

In your input data you have the following:

`60%     3,00%`
Should not it be `3.00%` like the others?

Comment: Yes it should, I normally use commas as decimal seperators and changed them to periods for to prevent confusion (since it's the international standard I believe). Does not change the question though. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem: When I use NUMBERVALUE() around my ROUNDUP() function, the formula works. Still have no clue why, for some reason it cannot interprete a the result of a ROUND function when the outcome is a value between 70% and 80%.

Everyone thanks for thinking along!

Answer (score 0):

Guess this is due to floating point that Excel can't evaluate properly.  But here I came up with two ways you can try.

[image]

1. `VLOOKUP`: Guess you will like to use this one.  Assuming you are entering the formula from `cell E2`.

```
=((D2-ROUNDDOWN(D2,1))/0.1)*(VLOOKUP(TRUNC(ROUNDUP(D2,1),2),$A$2:$B$12,2,0)-VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$B$12,2,0))+VLOOKUP(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$B$12,2,0)
```

2. `SLOPE`: As Gary's Student pointed out.  This is a very cool way to use.  But in order to determine the range dynamically, I have incorporate with `OFFSET` function to do the work.

```
=SLOPE(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$A$12,0),0,2),OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$A$12,0),0,2))*D2+INTERCEPT(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$A$12,0),0,2),OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(ROUNDDOWN(D2,1),$A$2:$A$12,0),0,2))
```